# iframe blocking my page click in react app

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone see a problem in this image ?

That `iframe` is basically blocking my page from **clicking** to anything.
It only happening on development. Site working fine in production.
It started after i used `react-markdown`. But they said they don't use iframe in the library.

Would it be because of `react-scripts` ?
I recently updated my `react, react-router-dom` but didn't `react-scripts` since there were potential (node related) errors if i updated to react-scripts v5
[image]

Comment: Same problem here and the only solution I have found is upgrading react-scripts to v5. I'm also looking for any solution without upgrading react-script. Please let me know if you find any.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix without upgrading the `react-scripts` to v5.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11880#issuecomment-1005409614